# ALAssetRepresentation as NSData for GIFs

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, nsdata

I'm try to allow users to pull images out of their Photos collections using `ALAssetsLibrary`.  Users can then upload these images.  My goal is to allow users to upload any GIFs they may have in their library w/o loosing any animation they may have.

For PNG and JPEG files I can grab the `ALAssetRepresentation`, use - `(CGImageRef)fullResolutionImage` to get a `CGImageRef`, and then save it to NSData using  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

However, because no similar function exists for GIF files, all I can do is covert the GIF to either JPEG or PNG, but then I lose the animation.

Is there either

1. a way to grab the NSData straight from an `ALAssetRepresentation` object or
2. a way to go from `ALAssetRepresentation` -> `CGImageRef` -> `NSData` without loosing any gif animation frames?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a quite simple way:

Use the getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: method of ALAssetRepresentation. This gives youthe raw file data of the ALAsset, in your case the GIF file.